# Angular 2+: Trigger an observable externally

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'd like to trigger an observable (obs) externally (e.g from another subscription).
All samples I found were internally by a timeout in the observer-implementation.

```
obs = new Observable (observer => { ... });  


someother.subsribe ((n) => 
           {
                    // trigger obs
                    // obs.next is not available
           });
```

Comment: You probably want `Subject` instead of  `Observable` if you want to call `next` at some point.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to call `next` from outside an Observable, you could use a `Subject` instead, which acts like an observable that can be called on to produce values externally.

```
const subject = new Subject()

subject.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('next:', value)
})

subject.next('some value')
```